# How to prove that this is a lattice?

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders

Given the poset $(X,\subseteq)$ with $X=\{T\subseteq\mathbb{N}\ |\ T$ is finite or $\mathbb{N}\setminus T$ is finite}

How can I prove, that for some arbitrary $X_1, X_2\subseteq X$ there exists the supremum and the infimum?

Comment: Can you guess what the supremum and the infimum would be?

Comment: @GitGud: Well, obviously the supremum would be the union and the infimum would be the intersection. But how do I prove that?

Comment: The same way you'd prove it for $\left(\mathcal P(\mathbb N),\subseteq\right)$. The real point of the problem is proving that $X_1\cap X_2\in X$ and $X_1\cap X_2\in X$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First prove that $X$ is closed to the union and intersection by considering all combinations:

1) If $X_1$ finite and $X_2$ finite then $X_1\cup X_2$ is finite and $X_1\cap X_2$ is finite

2) If $X_1$ finite and $\mathbb N \setminus X_2$ finite then $\mathbb N \setminus (X_1\cup X_2)\subseteq \mathbb N \setminus X_2$ is finite and $X_1\cap X_2$ is finite

3) If $\mathbb N \setminus X_1$ finite and $\mathbb N \setminus X_2$ finite then $\mathbb N \setminus (X_1\cup X_2)=(\mathbb N \setminus X_1)\cap(\mathbb N \setminus X_2)$ is finite and $\mathbb N \setminus (X_1\cap X_2)=(\mathbb N \setminus X_1)\cup(\mathbb N \setminus X_2)$ is finite

Then the union is upper bound:

$X_1\subseteq X_1\cup X_2$ and  $X_2\subseteq X_1\cup X_2$

Then the union is the least upper bound:
If $Y$ us another upper bound then:

$X_1\subseteq Y$ and  $X_2\subseteq Y$, so $X_1\cup X_2\subseteq Y$

Proof of the intersection being greatest lower bound works similarly (by duality).

Comment: Can you please explain 2) and 3) a little more? How do you know that $\mathbb{N}\setminus(X_1\cup X_2)\subseteq\mathbb{N}\setminus X_2$ is finite if $X_1$ and $\mathbb{N}\setminus X_2$ are finite?

Comment: If I start like this: Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be two elements of $X$, with $X_1$ finite and $X_2$ cofinite. How do I get to: ........ then $\mathbb{N}\setminus(X_1\cup X_2)\subseteq\mathbb{N}\setminus X_2$ is finite ?

Comment: $\mathbb N \setminus (X_1\cup X_2) \subseteq \mathbb N \setminus X_2$ is always true. For example consider $x\in \mathbb N$. Then

$$\ \\
x\notin X_1\cup X_2 \Leftrightarrow \neg (x\in X_1\cup X_2)\Leftrightarrow \neg (x\in X_1 \lor x \in X_2)\Leftrightarrow\\
\Leftrightarrow \neg (x\in X_1) \land \neg (x \in X_2)\Leftrightarrow x\notin X_1 \land x \notin X_2\Rightarrow x \notin X_2\\
\ 
$$

So $\mathbb N \setminus (X_1\cup X_2) \subseteq \mathbb N \setminus X_2$ But $\mathbb N \setminus X_2$ is finite and a subset of a finite set is itself finite.